# Can a raspberry Pi with windows 10 IOT run Visual Basic programs?

Tags: raspberry-pi

Can a raspberry pi with Windows 10 IOT run normal windows apps created in visual studio?

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 10 IoT core, you can run Windows 10 Universal applications (UWP) with a visual interface. In Visual Studio, start a new "Universal Windows" project with your chosen programming language. You can then code a GUI with for example XAML just like a desktop or mobile Windows 10 application. For example for C# use Visual C# -> Universal -> Blank App (Universal Windows).

You need the Windows SDK but that is included in the Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

To access the unique features of the device (like GPIO) you need to add a reference to "**Windows IoT Extension SDK**".

Examples on how to do it:

See this repository for samples of many kinds of different apps (you can just download a ZIP of all those and play with them): https://github.com/ms-iot/samples

Tutorials for the samples: 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/startcoding

Answer (score 0):

I also want to use VB6 on iot/ARM 
it seems that this feature is blocked in Win10 ioT

the best option for now is booting a MicroLinux Kernel for ARM with Wine

Answer (score 0):

No Visual Basic 6 will not work with Windows 10 IoT.  I have heard there are tools that allow it to work somewhat with Raspbian.

I have examples of Visual Basic using Visual Studio Community 2017 and the Raspberry Pi using Windows 10 IoT.  You can use the GPIO, SQL Server, Access files, send email(using LightBuz Libraries).  There are videos at A1entities.com and samples in my new book Raspberry Pi and Visual Basic Programming Windows 10 IoT.  It’s on Kindle and Amazon.